# Why is this regex not matching?

Tags: java, regex

I can't find out why my regex does not match a line when using java's String.matches method - it does match using on online regex tester.

Here is the Java-Code:

```
line.trim().replaceAll(" +", " ").matches("(const )?[a-zA-Z0-9\\*]*\\ [a-zA-Z0-9\\*]*[,|)]");
```

and the line that should be matched:

```
bool fLoad)   // somecomment
```

Does anybody have any ideas why this is so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`matches()` means it should match *completely*, i.e. the whole string fits the RE. Your RE does not allow anything after the ')'. Try using `find()` instead `matches()`.

Answer (score 1):

Java's `String.match()` doesn't work the way many other languages implement it: the *whole* input has to be matched, so add `.*` to each end of your regex:

```
line.trim().replaceAll(" +", " ").matches(".*(const )?[a-zA-Z0-9\\*]*\\ [a-zA-Z0-9\\*]*[,|)].*");
```

I tested this and your sample line returns `true` from `matches()`

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are attempting to match some sort of variable declaration in source code.

In your regex, you have this after the part that I imagine is meant to match "const (optionally) datatype":

```
"(const )?[a-zA-Z0-9\\*]*\\ "
```

Is the `\\` prior to the space intentional? Do you mean to match a single `\` ?

Comment: The space is intentional, since there should always be a space in the declaration between datatype and variable name.

Comment: but why do you need the double backslash before the space?